# How do I specify the date format of Tempus Dominus 6 (getdatepicker)?

Tags: javascript, date, datepicker, tempus-dominus-datetimepicker

I'm using version 6 of Tempus Dominus, whose documentation is found at https://getdatepicker.com/6/.

My question is:

- How do I set the date format?

I have this HTML control:

```html
<div class="col-auto">
    <label for="fromDateInput">From date:</label>
    <div class="input-group" id="fromDate" data-td-target-input="nearest" data-td-target-toggle="nearest">
        <input id="fromDateInput" type="text" class="form-control" data-td-target="#fromDate">
        <span class="input-group-text" data-td-target="#fromDate" data-td-toggle="datetimepicker"><span class="fa-solid fa-calendar"></span></span>
    </div>
</div>
```

And I have the following JavaScript configuration of the Tempus Dominus datepicker control:

```js
const picker = new tempusDominus.TempusDominus(document.getElementById('fromDate'), {
    display: {
        components: {
            clock: false
        }
    },
    localization: {
        startOfTheWeek: 1
    }
});
```

In the browser, the control looks like this:

[image: controller]

I then select a date:

[image: controller selection of date]

As you can see in the field, the date is written as `06/22/2022`. However, I would like the format to be `YYYY-MM-DD`, such that the date in this instance becomes `2022-06-22`. How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found documentation for it on the plugins overview page: https://getdatepicker.com/6/plugins/

It has the following example:

> **Per Picker**
> It is possible to use this system per picker. For instance:
>
> ```js
> const td = new tempusDominus.TempusDominus(document.getElementById('datetimepicker1'));
> td.dates.formatInput = function(date) { {return moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY') } }
> ```
>
> The code above would affect a single picker but not globally. You could easily adapt this code to have a common formatting function taking in a format string.

So I adapted my code in the following way:

```js
const picker = new tempusDominus.TempusDominus(document.getElementById('fromDate'), {
    display: {
        components: {
            clock: false
        }
    },
    localization: {
        startOfTheWeek: 1
    }
});
picker.dates.formatInput = date => moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

And now the date format looks like I want it:

[image: date format controller]

As you can see, the date is now written `2022-06-22`.

Comment: This works fine on empty input fields. But how to initialize a predefined value: I pass 2023-12-31 16:00 and it is converted to 12/31/2023 16:00

Answer (score 1):

And in case you don't want to use moment.js…

```
const picker = new tempusDominus.TempusDominus(document.getElementById('fromDate'), {});
picker.dates.formatInput = date =>
    date.getFullYear() + '-' +
    ("0"+(date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" +
    ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
```

Answer (score 0):

After submit form, correct format changes to default format.

Answer (score 0):

if using jquery, and your plugin is >= 6.2.7.

- load the plugins `customDateFormat.js`
- set your tempusDominus to extend custom format

```
 tempusDominus.extend(window.tempusDominus.plugins.customDateFormat);
```

Complete code like

```
tempusDominus.extend(window.tempusDominus.plugins.customDateFormat);

$('#fromDate').tempusDominus({
      localization: {
        format: 'yyyy-MM-dd',
      }
    });
```

Reference:
https://getdatepicker.com/6/plugins/customDateFormat.html